# HTML Table with images

Tags: html, css

so i am currently re making the site for my university's drama department and i want to add 3 images side by side (with spacing between them). They also need to have captions. But the caption needs to have a header (that is styled differently than the caption itself) followed by the caption itself. having looked around here and other places i figured i would be able to do this using a table since formatting size would be easiest this way. I have been at this portion of the site for almost 1 month and have tried numerous other methods (divs, tables, etc.) I was wondering if someone else has done something like this and would be able to impart some advice. The site currently is located here: [drama site](http://www.queensu.ca/drama/template1.html). Any help would be appreciated (i hope this follows the guidelines, first time asker)

Edit: The following is the portion of the code i need help with:

```js
function windowSize() {
  var w = var w = document.getElementById('body').clientWidth;
  document.getElementById('newsTable').style.width = w + 'px';
  document.getElementById('newsItems').style.height = document.getElementById('newsItems').clientWidth + 'px';
}
```

```html
<body id="body" onload="windowSize();getCurrentPage();" onresize="windowSize()">
  <table id="newsTable" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td id="newsItems" align="center" background="http://i.imgbox.com/5GLGmmDE.gif">1</td>
      <td id="newsItems" align="center" background="http://i.imgbox.com/5GLGmmDE.gif">2</td>
      <td id="newsItems" align="center" background="http://i.imgbox.com/5GLGmmDE.gif">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="newsItems" align="center">4</td>
      <td id="newsItems" align="center">5</td>
      <td id="newsItems" align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

I don't want the pictures to be as big as they are in the link, i would like them to be a bit smaller. I would also like some room between them. Currently when the page gets bigger the image starts to repeat. If i took the repeat off then it would have blank space where it would normally repeat

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the portion of code that you need help with?

Comment: For one thing some higher-res images could help. Try setting either border-spacing or padding in the table data elements to different values to see what you like on the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the nicest option would be to use bootstrap. It can do a lot of the columner work for you. But if that sounds a little complex, here is a simple fiddle with three images side by side.
http://jsfiddle.net/44uv9a2m/

I'm just wrapping the images and their captions in divs, then giving them a fixed width.

```css
.oneThird{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    margin:.5%;
}
.oneThird img{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="oneThird">
    <img src="http://www.photosnewhd.com/media/images/picture-wallpaper.jpg"></img>
    <p>Caption</p>
</div>
<div class="oneThird">
    <img src="http://www.photosnewhd.com/media/images/picture-wallpaper.jpg"></img>
    <p>Caption</p>
</div>
<div class="oneThird">
    <img src="http://www.photosnewhd.com/media/images/picture-wallpaper.jpg"></img>
    <p>Caption</p>
</div>
```

*** Edit ***
This is a basic bootstrap example.
http://www.bootply.com/n6AdJPYIe3

Comment: So this works quite well and is basically what i want. How would i get it centered on my page? or how do i get it so the right side lines up with the rest of the site? http://www.queensu.ca/drama/template.html

Comment: That rather depends on what the rest of your site looks like, but generally if you have body set to 100% width and height and this div is under the body then it should look fine, then follow suit with the rest of your divs. I'm not sure how complex you want to get on your site.